# Renaming dataframe columns with regex and dictionary

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
code_0101    code_0102    code_0103    code_0104    ...
0            1            2            3            ...
...          ...          ...          ...
```

I also have a dictionary:

```
{'0101': 'cirurgical_procedures', '0102': 'medical_care', '0103': 'remedy', ...}
```

I want to apply a regex to dataframe column and replace the code numbers accorging to my dictionary, and get something like this:

```
code_cirurgical_procedures    code_medical_care       ...
0                             1                       ...
...                           ...
```

How can I do these two steps, specially the second, about the dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `series.replace` to replace and assign back to columns

```
d = {'0101': 'cirurgical_procedures', '0102': 'medical_care', '0103': 'remedy'}
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(d, regex=True)

Out[12]:
   code_cirurgical_procedures  code_medical_care  code_remedy  code_0104
0                           0                  1            2          3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `code` as perfix you can use a dict comprehension,

```
 cols = {'0101': 'cirurgical_procedures', '0102': 'medical_care', '0103': 'remedy'}

df.rename(columns = {f"code_{k}": f"code_{v}" for k,v in cols.items()})
```

Comment: Thank you! First time seeing a dict comprehension

Comment: But just for curiosity, if the preffix isn't the same in every column, what could I do?